# How is Value determined for an Anchor Tag with Microdata?

Tags: html, seo, microdata, schema.org

How do Google and others determine the value of an `itemprop` on an Anchor tag?

```
 <a href="foo.html" itemprop="barprop">Name Of Link</a>
```

In the example above, is the itemprop's value the `href` attribute, much like how the `link` tag is parsed? Or is the value the `innerHTML`, as a standard block element is parsed?

I've searched quite a bit and cannot find the answer. I'm open to all answers, but I'd very much like a source for the answers given so I can further investigate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the value of ordinary elements like div and spans is not their innerHTML value but their textContent value. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#values for the full details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Microdata spec (which is now merely W3C *Note*) [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values):

> **If the element is an `a`, `area`, or `link` element**
>   The value is the absolute URL that results from resolving the value of the element's `href` attribute relative to the element at the time the attribute is set, or the empty string if there is no such attribute or if resolving it results in an error.

Exception: when the `a`/`area`/`link` element has an `itemscope` attribute, then the `itemprop` "value is the item created by the element", not the `href` value.

Answer (score 4):

It seems I found the answer not long after posting this. However, rather than deleting the question, I'm sure there are others out there who are wondering the same thing.

The short answer is: It uses the `href` attribute.

The long answer can be found here: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_canonical