# How to use Schema.org 'name' and 'url' in <a> tag?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

This code was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22283736/1591669) to me:

```
<a itemprop="url" href="…"><span itemprop="name">…</span></a>
```

But do you think this code is also correct?

```
<li class="menu-home" itemprop="url">
     <a href="http://example.com/" title="Home" itemprop="name">Home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not correct. There are [special parsing rules for `a`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283706/1591669).

Currently you’d have these name-value pairs:

```
url: Home
name: http://any.com/
```

But, of course, it should be the other way around. So:

- The `url` property needs to be specified on `a`.
- The `name` property needs to be specified on something other than `a`.

You could use, for example:

```html
<li itemprop="name">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://any.com/">Home</a>
</li>
```

(See also [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58944/17633) to a similar question on Webmasters.)

Comment: Thanks for your full answer :)