# How to add Schema.org type for feeds?

Tags: html, feed, microdata, schema.org

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" >
  <span itemprop="???"><a href="feed.rss">RSS of this section</a></span>

  <ul>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://example.net/Item">
    <a href="" itemprop="url">title</a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

What about feed in `span` tag? Is there any Schema.org type for that?

Comment: Why are you using `ItemList` here? You are missing a `ul`/`ol` element. Note that the `url` property you used would be for specifying a URL for the whole list, not for a single list entry.

Comment: Thanks for your Note...I will Edit my post. please give me your commnet again :)

Comment: Yes, now it’s correct except for `http://schema.org/Item`, which does not exist.

Comment: Very Thanks Dear Unor...You realy was a big helper for me yesterday and today...Yes 'item' dose not exist. But I underestood your mean.

Comment: Ah, there was still an HTML error: `span` can’t be a child of `ul`. I edited your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2019:** Schema.org will likely have a `webFeed` property for podcasts soon ([see pull request](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/pull/2007)), and its definition will probably be extended so that it can be used in non-podcast contexts, too, but I’d doubt that it will be possible to add it to `ItemList`.

---

The Schema.org vocabulary doesn’t define a class or a property for [feeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed).

But HTML5 defines a way to link feeds: use the [`alternate` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/links.html#link-type-alternate) together with the [`type` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/document-metadata.html#processing-link-type) set to `application/rss+xml` resp. `application/atom+xml`.

```html
<a href="feed.rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">RSS of this section</a>
```

(The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581639/1591669) feed linked that way is treated as the default feed for autodiscovery; so when you have several section feeds linked on the same page, you should probably make sure that the first feed is a general one and not specific to only one section.)

Comment: Thnak you. But what about 'sameAs' property? Can you use it too?

Comment: @user3307827: If the `ItemList` has the same entries as the feed, yes, you might use [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) (although its description talks about "Web page", but I guess they don’t intend to restrict it like that).

Comment: @user3307827: Also note that if you want to use `sameAs`, you [have to use this property on the `a` element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22284473/1591669) (not on the `span`), because `sameAs` expects a URL.

Comment: schema.org [defines](https://schema.org/sameAs) `sameAs` as a "URL of a reference Web page that unambiguously indicates the item's identity. E.g. the URL of the item's Wikipedia page, Wikidata entry, or official website." I don't see how a web feed fits that criteria.

Comment: @JoshHabdas: True, thanks for the notice. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like a PDF or AMP page RSS is simply an output format, or *encoding*, of a document or resource. Here's what schema.org [has to say](https://schema.org/WebPage) about encoding:

> In cases where a [`CreativeWork`](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) has several media type representations, [`encoding`](https://schema.org/encoding) can be used to indicate each [`MediaObject`](https://schema.org/MediaObject) alongside particular [`encodingFormat`](https://schema.org/encodingFormat) information.

Applied to your example using microdata:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MediaObject">
  <meta itemprop="encodingFormat" content="application/rss+xml">
  <a itemprop="contentUrl" href="feed.rss">
    <span itemprop="description">RSS of this section</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And tested [with Yandex](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) results in the following:

```
mediaobject
  itemType = http://schema.org/MediaObject
  encodingformat = application/rss+xml
  contenturl
    href = feed.rss
    text = RSS of this section
  description = RSS of this section
```

You can also use JSON-LD or RDFa instead of microdata if you prefer.