# Can the order in which adding link and meta tags on head of a webpage have any adverse effect?

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, meta, html-head

I have added this code to my webpage with .php extension

```php
<?php include_once("cssheadertop.php")?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
<?php include_once("cssheaderbottom.php")?>
```

Now, cssheadertop.php contains the following code

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>8mags - CSS Lessons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The cssheaderbottom.php file has following code

```html
  <style>
  page specific style here.
  </style>
  </head>
```

I want to add meta description and meta keywords tag between

```php
 <?php include_once("cssheadertop.php")?>
```

and

```php
 <?php include_once("cssheaderbottom.php")?>
```

just like the link tag I have added.

Can it pose any problem in rendering or SEO?

Comment: Why do you think there could be something problematic about it?

Comment: It is because almost everywhere I see it is in this order: meta, link, script. So, I thought Search engines might stop looking for meta tags after it finds first link tag.

Comment: I have also changed the location of title tag and put it between two includes files is this alright?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from a few exceptions, the order of childs in the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) doesn’t matter.

That said, consumers like search engines may of course do what they want (e.g., ignoring every third element, just for the fun of it), but discussing the possible behaviour of undesignated consumers is off-topic here.

The exceptions:

- [`meta`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)-[`charset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#charset) should ideally be the first child (i.e., the element must be within the first 1024 bytes of the document, and at best before any non-ASCII characters)
- [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) should ideally be the second child (i.e., it must come before any other element in `head` that has a URI as attribute value)
- those [`link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) and [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) elements that the user agents wants to process are by default processed in the order they appear
- the order of `link`-`stylesheet` and [`style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) elements can play a role for applying CSS
- the first `link`-[`alternate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate) with a `type` of `application/rss+xml` or `application/atom+xml` is "the default syndication feed for the purposes of feed autodiscovery"