# Do <head> elements need to be at the very top of the code to serve SEO purpose?

Tags: php, html, seo, html-head

I'm working on SEO optimization right now and I was wondering if things like `<title>` and `<meta>` can be placed in the middle of the code or at the bottom?

Will they still be recognized by search engines just as they are when they're at the top? I need to have them bellow my php code in order for them to display variables defined by that php code.

Additionally, do they have to be inside `<head>`?

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
include ('./includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php
$error = "";
$date_q = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['xyz']));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title><?php echo $subject ?></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
<meta name="author" content="<?php echo $subject ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $subject ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $subject ?>">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: No they can't be in the middle or bottom.. That's an illegal markup if you place these tags at the bottom or in the middle of your code.  And yes, these tags you need to put them in your `<head>`. Please review this course: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: @C0dekid Ok, but how do I get php variables into `<meta>` tags then, it those variable are defined bellow the `<meta>` tags?

Comment: Do you have an example from what you trying to archive? If so, please add it to your question. It makes it a lot easier for us to give you answers. You need to have these variables above the `<DOCTYPE html>` tag if you want to use PHP in your meta tags.

Comment: @C0dekid I have added my code. You will notice there is `include()` above it and some php code. If I put `<head>` items at the top of the document (above `include()` and php code), they stop working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are mostly about the unknown inner workings of one company instead of technical facts. Try at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The tags need to be *at the top* of the **resulting HTML**. Look at the HTML source in your browser. Is the `<head>` tag on top and contains your meta elements? Fine, then you're producing valid HTML. Nobody cares whether there's PHP code in your .php source file before that.

Comment: @deceze No, I'm not asking a SEO question, I'm asking if the <head> items have to be at the top of the document in order to be recognized by search engines. That's a technical question.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion what "at the top" means. If you're talking about the resulting HTML, then it's an SEO question. If you're talking about your .php source code, it's a technical question. See my above comment, hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @deceze Ok, but what about `include ('./includes/header.php')` It's above `<head>` and `header.php` contains some html code

Comment: So what is the resulting HTML document that the browser sees? It has HTML before `<!DOCTYPE html>`?! Then it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, that helped.

Comment: What on earth is `mysql_real_escape_string` doing there? You're putting the output into an HTML document, not into a MySQL database! (And the function has been removed from PHP anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Your visitors (including search engine bots) can of course only see *the output* of your PHP, i.e., the plain HTML document.

The [`html` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#the-html-element) must contain

> A [`head`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) element followed by a [`body`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-body-element) element.

Under certain conditions (explained in the linked element definitions) you may omit the opening/closing tags of the `html`, `head`, and `body` elements. But you still have a `head` and a `body` then, and the `head` content has to come before the `body` content.

Inside of your `head`, [the order of the elements can matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581639/1591669).