# How to prioritize tags orders in Head in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I have a `Next.js` application that each page renders a tag in its head.
my problem is that tags in `_app.js` are at the top of all tags.
how can i move others pages tags above `_app.js` tags?

Comment: Which tag are you referring to? The order [mostly doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581639).

Comment: @brc-dd title and meta description