# Can schema.org's email property use the href value?

Tags: html, email, schema.org, microdata

What I would like to do is take the value of the `href` and assign it to the email property.  Right now, I have something like this

`<a href="mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu" itemprop="email">email</a>`

The result is email="email"

The schema.org documentation has an example that uses the following syntax

`<a href="mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu" itemprop="email">jane-doe@xyz.edu</a>`

The result is email=jane-doe@xyz.edu

Do I have to spell out my email address in order to mark it up using microdata?

I know that some properties such as URL actually grab the `href` value instead of the text surrounded by the HTML tag.  Is this possible to configure for the email property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema.org’s [`email` property](http://schema.org/email) expects *Text* as value.

It’s odd. In my opinion it should take URL instead, or at least allow boths ways ("*Text* or *URL*", as it’s the case with the [`menu` property](http://schema.org/menu), too).
I can only guess that they chose *Text* because some publishers don’t want to specify their real email address for spam prevention reasons (for example, "john -at- example dot org" isn’t an URL, of course; this is also used as an example in [Organization](http://schema.org/Organization): `<span itemprop="email">secretariat(at)google.org</span>`), or because some would forget to add the protocol `mailto:`, but both of these "issues" aren’t reasons *not* to allow URL *in addition*.

Here’s a related thread in the public-vocabs mailing list:
[**Expected type(s) for email should include URL**](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2013Jul/thread.html#msg139)

If you don’t want to have the email address visible on the page, and you want to follow the current definition by using Text, you could use the `meta` element as an ugly workaround:

```
<p>
  <a href="mailto:john@example.com">email</a>
  <meta itemprop="email" content="john@example.com" />
  <!-- the value is not an URL but text -->
</p>
```

---

Side note:

Every conforming Microdata parser must extract "email: mailto:john@example.com" for this markup:

```
<a href="mailto:john@example.com" itemprop="email">email</a>
```

As the `email` property is used on `a`, the [value is the `href` content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283706/1591669) and not the element content.